# Edit a thumbnail in Rails

Tags: software-development, open-source, images, image-processing

I want to add a cropping feature in my Rails project that's like what Facebook has today.
When you upload your image you can edit the thumbnail so that it shows the part of the image that you want to show in the thumbnail.

Is there a gem that makes this possible in Rails?
I've read the RMagick and Paperclip docs and they don't have this feature.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if this really belongs to sofwarerecs but I think you want [papercrop](https://github.com/rsantamaria/papercrop), which is an implementation of [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)... If you have a RailsCasts Pro subscription you can also take a look at [#182 Cropping Images (revised)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised)

Comment: That's exactly what I meant! Thank you so much for the tip!

Comment: I've added my suggestion as an answer since you find it useful and it [evidently](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-alright-to-ask-for-programming-tools) fits in here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: JCrop]

**[Homepage](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html)** –
[Examples](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php)

*The jQuery plugin Jcrop is a quick and easy way to add image cropping functionality to your web application.*

#### Feature Overview

- Attaches unobtrusively to images or block objects
- Supports aspect ratio locking & minSize/maxSize setting
- Callbacks for selection done, or while moving
- Support for CSS styling, now uses LESS
- Touch support for mobile devices

#### Resources for Ruby on Rails

- **[Papercrop](https://github.com/rsantamaria/papercrop)** An easy extension for [Paperclip gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to crop your image uploads using jCrop.
- **[RailsCasts #182 revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised)** *(paid subscription required)* Allow users to interactively crop uploaded images using Jcrop and Carrierwave. Includes a live preview that shows the resulting image.
  <sub>You can also watch the [old episode from 2009](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images) for free.</sub>